# How to retrieve DirectoryEntry from a DirectoryEntry and a DN

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, ldap

I have a `DirectoryEntry` object representing a user.  From the `DirectoryEntry.Properties` collection, I am retrieving the `"manager"` property, which will give me a Distinguished Name ("DN") value for the user's manager.

Can I retrieve a `DirectoryEntry` object for the manager from just these two objects?  If so, how?

I'm envisioning something like `DirectoryEntry.GetEntryFromDN(dnManager);`, but I cannot find a similar call.

Just to clarify, the DirectoryEntry and DN are the only pieces of information I have.  I cannot instantiate a new `DirectoryEntry` because then I would have have to either use the default Directory and credentials or have the Directory name/port and username/password.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DirectoryEntry User = YourPreExistingUser();

string managerDN = User.Properties["manager"][0].ToString();

// Browse up the object hierarchy using DirectoryEntry.Parent looking for the
// domain root (domainDNS) object starting from the existing user.
DirectoryEntry DomainRoot = User;

do
{
    DomainRoot = DomainRoot.Parent;
}
while (DomainRoot.SchemaClassName != "domainDNS");

// Use the domain root object we found as the search root for a DirectorySearcher
// and search for the manager's distinguished name.
using (DirectorySearcher Search = new DirectorySearcher())
{
    Search.SearchRoot = DomainRoot;

    Search.Filter = "(&(distinguishedName=" + managerDN + "))";

    SearchResult Result = Search.FindOne();

    if (Result != null)
    {
        DirectoryEntry Manager = Result.GetDirectoryEntry();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would rather not traverse the directory tree myself or construct a search query, but it looks like this is the best answer for now.

Comment: It might not be the quickest way ( it seems a tad slow on my machine) but it really helped me for a quick fix. Thnx :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new DirectoryEntry instance providing the the DN as argument and then
attempt to bind (by refreshing properties for example).

DirectoryEntry e = new DirectoryEntry(dn, "u", "p");
e.RefreshCache();

Comment: But that creates the `DirectoryEntry` with the default Directory only; I need to account for the Directory not using the machine's default directory.  It also looks like you're assuming that I can statically provide the credentials to connect.